# Linux file size differes

Tags: linux, file, centos, size

In server A I have compressed a directory(88GB) using tar -zcf mydir.tar.gz mydir/ command. Then on server B I downloaded the compressed file from server A using wget command and uncompressed it on the server B. Now the directory size is different on both servers. Both servers are running CentOS7.
Any one has any idea that why and how to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: What do you mean by the "directory size"?  Could you post the command you use to determine the difference, and the output of that command from both servers showing the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why this issue appears but maybe how to fix or create a work-a-round around it. Maybe you can use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) for your case.